# Node JS, run same function after it is finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, settimeout

My applications need to poll every 2 seconds if there are changes. For now i use setInterval, but sometimes `myFunction` takes longer then 2 seconds to execute and records in the mysql database will be inserted twice. I make use of the async lib in myFunction..

So i need this...

When myFunction is finished

`method.myFunction() =>`

It needs to run again (but only when it is finished). `setInterval` with x seconds is not an option. This is because they can run at the same time if the scripts takes longer then  x seconds.

How can i run `myFunction` again after x seconds, but only when `myFunction` is done with processing
So in psuedo code it would be this

`if method.myFunction == finished
wait 2 seconds
 run method.myFunction again`

Comment: can you share code snippet

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I used modified your code to this and it works like a charm...

```html
var backup_timeout_seconds = 5000;
var main_rest_seconds = 2000;
function godMethod(timeout){


    var backuptimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        godMethod(main_rest_seconds);
        console.log("Called backup timeout, script is stuck...");
    }, backup_timeout_seconds);


    
    Pollforbids.pollForNewBids2(,function (err,res) {
        executor(timeout);
        clearTimeout(backuptimeout);
    });



}





function executor(interval){
    setTimeout(function(){
        godMethod(interval);
    }, interval);

}

godMethod(main_rest_seconds);
```

Comment: But why did you remove the answered 'tick' mark from mine? Coz i answered your question and your issue solved right?

Answer (score 6):

so with the below code, your method will be called once every seconds when the function execution is over.

```
function godMethod(){
    /* do what ever you want but call executor once you are done with everything */
    someCallbackForInsertion(data, function(){
        executor()
    })      
}

function executor(){
    setInterval(function(){
        godMethod()
    }, 2000);   
}

executor();
```

So here you call the executor on start of the server, then after 2 seconds it calls the godMethod then do your insertion/whatever. After successfully inserted call the executor again.

Comment: Oke thank you. So if the godMethod takes 5 seconds to execute, it just waits..? This will prevent that my code will be executed  simultaneously ?

Comment: yeah, your godMethod will never execute simultaneously and it will execute exactly only after 2 seconds of the previous godMethod complete execution.

Comment: If it works can you accept it as answer? so will be helpful for others who seek the same..

Answer (score 1):

Use callback or, even better, Promises to let next poll execute only when the previous process is completed.

Comment: i use async as a promise